# How to avoid page numbering on the title page?

Tags: titles, page-numbering

I am trying to write an article using TeXstudio and the first page is dedicated for title, name of the author and date. I am numbering the pages in roman from the second page but arabic page numbering started from the title page without any command. How do I remove it?

Comment: Please add to your question a *complete*, minimal document showing the relevant settings.

Comment: After `\begin{document}` put `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but as @GonzaloMedina said, if you provide MWE, then we can easier help you.

Comment: @Zarko I think it would be more suited after `\maketitle` ;-)

Comment: I am really sorry sir I just started learning LATEX and came to know that such a website exists only today. So I did not know how to put forth my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the standard `article` class, the `titlepage` class option takes care of this:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}

\author{The Author}
\title{The title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

test text

\end{document}
```